# Shortcode works in the post body and header but not in the excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

The shortcode `MEM_PRICE` is used to detect the user country and output a price.

The function `get_user_geo_country()` is used to detect the user country and set two constants `USER_COUNTRY` and `MEM_PRICE_PLUS`. It is located in the functions.php file and called from header.php. If the visitor is from the UK the Membership price is 4 else it is 5. I have echoed it out in the header and it prints the correct values.

```
/* Function to detect user country - Start */
function get_user_geo_country(){
    $geo = new WC_Geolocation();
    $user_ip = $geo->get_ip_address();
    $user_geo = $geo->geolocate_ip($user_ip);
    if ($user_geo['country'] === "UK") {
        define( 'USER_COUNTRY', "UK" );
        define( 'MEM_PRICE_PLUS', 4 );
    } else {
        define( 'USER_COUNTRY', "WW" );
        define( 'MEM_PRICE_PLUS', 5 );
    }
    return USER_COUNTRY;
}
/* Function to detect user country - End */

/* Function to output country specific membership price - Start */
function country_mem_price() {
    return (USER_COUNTRY === 'UK' ? "£" .MEM_PRICE_PLUS : "$" .MEM_PRICE_PLUS);
}
add_shortcode('MEM_PRICE', 'country_mem_price');
/* Function to output country specific membership price - End */
```

Header.php code

```
if ( get_user_geo_country() == "UK" ) {
    echo MEM_PRICE_PLUS;
} else {
    echo MEM_PRICE_PLUS;
}
```

The shortcode `MEM_PRICE` also works in the post body but doesn't work in the excerpt. It prints `$MEM_PRICE_PLUS` instead of the values. There is also the following warning generated in the error log.

> [18-Jun-2021 05:23:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant
> USER_COUNTRY - assumed 'USER_COUNTRY' (this will throw an Error in a
> future version of PHP) in
> /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/themes/abc/functions.php on
> line 234
>
> [18-Jun-2021 05:23:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant
> MEM_PRICE_PLUS - assumed 'MEM_PRICE_PLUS' (this will throw an Error in
> a future version of PHP) in
> /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/themes/abc/functions.php on
> line 234

Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe the excerpt is _created_, before the header code calls the function? You could just check if `USER_COUNTRY` is already defined, in your shortcode function, and if not you call `get_user_geo_country` there.

Comment: @CBroe thanks. You were right. The excerpt was created before my call to the function in the header.